# random generation of lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, finite-fields, simple-groups, probabilistic-method

It is well known that a nonabelian finite simple group, say $\mathrm{PSL}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$, can be generated by two elements. In fact, the probability that two elements generate it tends to $1$ as the size of the group tends to infinity.

Is the same result about probabilistic generation known to hold for Lie algebras over finite fields, say $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$?

Comment: Yes, at least for $p>3$, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi0xbaP7s78AhXJpIsKHfgUCeUQFnoECAkQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fdocument%3Frepid%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf%26doi%3De7d0b41ef9bc913d7658427f55dfcafe1e699ca1&usg=AOvVaw0N8zRZA4jj_qV4cjVsksVU). See also the "one and a half" generation theorems.

Comment: Nice, thank you! How about the probability that two random elements generate it as the size tends to infinity?

Comment: I suppose you mean random generation for *simple* Lie algebras over $\Bbb F_p$. There is no classification yet for simple Lie algebras over $\Bbb F_p$ (only over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p\ge 5$). For $p=2$ and $p=3$ there are really many non-standard simple modular Lie algebras. So I am not sure what is known beyond the linked paper above.

Comment: I see. Even just the case $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$ would be interesting.

Comment: For $p\mid n$ this Lie algebra is no longer simple, as it has a nontrivial center. But anyway, this would be interesting. I haven't seen results here (only for random generation of  simple algebraic groups over local fields by Y. Barnea).